# function to find number of ways u can split n objects using parts up to m

Tags: java, recursion

I'm using recursion to solve the problem. On paper my answer should work so I went wrong with the code. However, I can't figure exactly where the problem is.

```
public class Partition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(part(6,4));
    }

    public static int part(int n, int m) {
        if (n==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(m == 0 || n<0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return part(n-m, m) + part(n, m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output were you expecting (and why) and what are you getting instead?

Comment: This looks like it will run forever and never exit. Since in your example `part(6, 4)` will go to the else-block and call `part(6, 4)` and so on

Comment: im getting a stack trace but im ment to get 9 partitions

Comment: You don't need a base case. You already have two base cases. What you need (apparently) is a way to to reduce _m_ and/or _n_ down to zero to escape the recursive calls.

Comment: like a  m-- n-- at bottom

Comment: Isn't the math rule behind that `part(n, m) = part(n-1, m) + part(n-1, m-1)` ?

Comment: @vincrichaud `m-1` and `n-1` won't do it because the result will not be stored back in the variables. You need `m--` and `n--`.

Comment: @hfontanez no need to store it there, it won't get re-used

Comment: @Nuva_rad I answered your question. As you indicated, the function returns 9. You need to test with other values to make sure the solution is indeed correct and not just working by chance. I will appreciate if you upvote and select my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce `m` only for the problem to return 9 as you indicated.

```
public static int part (int n, int m) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (m == 0 || n < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return part(n - m, m--) + part(n, m);
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers this works although i have been programming for 3 months recursion always confuses me this answer works cheers for this

Comment: @Nuva_rad we all go through this. Even I get confused with recursion from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if it is to compute the [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) it should look like this :

```
public static int part(int n, int m) {
    if(m>n) { //This prevent a wrong input from the user
        return part(m, n);
    } else if (m==0 || m==n) { //This is your base case
        return 1;
    } else if(m < 0 || n<0) { //this should not happened, but you never know
        return 0;
    }  else { //this is where you're making mistake(s)
        //I don't know if I'm using the formula you are looking for
        //But if not, make sure yours do not use part(n, m) otherwise it will run forever
        return part(n-1, m) + part(n-1, m-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong IMO. You changed the algorithm by replacing `n - m` with `n-1`. The solution to the problem is just to reduce _m_ and/or _n_. By reducing _m_, the part `n - m` is already reducing the first argument. This is why `m--` should be used instead of `m-1`.

Comment: base case `m==n => 1` means we distinguish neither objects nor partitions and partitions are not empty. In this case the result for (3,2) should be 1